# 16.04 kernel's intel graphics driver

Tags: 16.04, drivers

How do I know that the current release kernel's intel graphics driver support which intel graphics?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure what you're asking, but `sudo lshw -C video` should list-hardware of video class, where you should see a "driver=" telling you what driver is being used.

Comment: I meant that how do I know a kernel's intel driver can drive a specific intel graphics(etc. Intel® HD Graphics for Intel® Celeron® Processor N3000 Series).

Comment: The N3000 was introduced in Q1 2015 (https://ark.intel.com/products/87259/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N3000-2M-Cache-up-to-2-08-GHz-) so kernels later than release-date will have drivers created by intel for it  (intel decide what the module for it does).  Intel write their own open-source drivers adding them to the kernel.  That page also tells you "20180807" is the latest microcode firmware available for linux.  I provided the command in last comment that lets you see driver, you can use `lsmod` to list [loaded] modules (ie. drivers) running to verify what is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Best to check with Intel - ie.

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005526/graphics-drivers.html

> Intel® Celeron® Processor N3000, N3050, N3150 January 2015    Yes (*linux support*)

The N3000 was introduced in Q1 2015 (https://ark.intel.com/products/87259/Intel-Celeron-Processor-N3000-2M-Cache-up-to-2-08-GHz-) so kernels later than release-date will have drivers created by intel for it, as intel push their own kernel module (driver) code into the kernels themselves.

That page also tells you

> 20180807

is the latest microcode firmware available for linux.

You can use the command `sudo lshw -C video` to list hardware of class 'video', where the "driver=" bit will tell you what kernel module (driver) is being used.